# How to Fill in Blank Spaces When Padding Does Not Work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out why I can't fill this spot, despite trying many things I have been unable to figure out how to fix it. I tried padding the top, but to no avail. I have provided the code below as well as a picture of the space I'm talking about. In the picture there's a white space between the header 2 and the gray area that has a brief summary. I have tried padding and also increasing the height of the background color, but it doesn't seem to work. Thank you in advance for reading this and I really do thank you for taking the time to help me figure this out.

```js
  $(document).ready(function()){
                        $("figure img + figcaption").prev().addClass('hasCaption');
                        
                        
                       
                        
                        });
```

```css
 .body{
        margin: 0px;
        
      }
      .homeButton{
        width: 40px;
        
      }
      #MidPort{
        background-image: url("http://www.geocities.ws/spahealthcare/pic/dark-green-home-button.png");
        background-size:cover;
        position:absolute;
        margin-left:1565px;
        bottom:10px;
      
      }
      .topnav{
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: Times New Roman;
        position:fixed;
        top 0;
        width:100%;
      }
      #bg2{
        background-color:red;
        
      }  
      
       ul{
         list-style-type:none;
         margin:0;
         padding:0;
         overflow: hidden;
         background-color: #333
     }
      li{
        float:left;
        border-right:1px solid #bbb;
        
        
      }    
       li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover {
        background-color: red;
    }
            
      .active{
        background-color:#4CAF50;
        }
       li a:hover:not(.active) 
      {
        background-color: #111; 
       }
      li:last-child{
        border-right:none;
        
      }
      #margintop1{
        margin-top: .5cm;
        font-family: Gadget;
        
    }
      .jumbotron{
        height:175px;
        background-color:#808080;
       
      }
    
      hr.style17 {
     border-top: 1px solid #8c8b8b;
     text-align: center;
      }
      hr.style17:after {
     content: '§';
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
     top: -14px;
     padding: 0 10px;
     background: #f0f0f0;
     color: #8c8b8b;
     font-size: 18px;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
     transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
      img.hasCaption {
      padding-bottom: 50px;
    }
    
    figcaption {
      position: absolute;
      left: 14px;
      right: 14px;
      bottom: 16px;
      background-color: white;
      text-align: center;
      color: blue;
      font-family: 'Reenie Beanie', cursive;
      font-size: 30px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
      figure {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      -moz-transform:rotate(-5deg);
      -webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg);
      -ms-transform:rotate(-5deg);
      transform:rotate(-5deg);
    }
    
    img {
      border-color: white;
      border-width: 15px;
      -moz-border-image: url(http://tobias-reinhardt.de/img/frame.png) 15 stretch;
      border-image: url(http://tobias-reinhardt.de/img/frame.png) 15 stretch;
      border-style: solid;
      margin: auto;
    }
      #imgR{
        margin-left:1285px;
        height:400px;
        
        
      }
     
      font{
        font-family:Gadget;
       }
      section{
        background-color:#00FFFF;
        margin-bottom:10cm;
        font-family:Gadget;
      }
      
        
      }
```

```html
    
    <!-- Check to see if the navigation bar remains at the bottom if I use the nav class instead of ul. If not, revert back to ul for when the user scrolls down-->
    
    
    
    <div>
       <header>
    <!--<div class="container">-->
     
      
      
          <h2 class="topnav" id="cs2">
             <ul>
                <li><a class="active"                                             href="/home">Home</a></li>                                               
            <li><a  href="/About me">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li id="MidPort"><a href="/Home"></a></li>
           </ul>
         </h2>
       </header>
    </div>
      <body> 
        <div class="intro-text">  
          <div class="jumbotron">
             <div> 
              <p id="margintop1"style="margin-right:200px;">
                <font color="white">Front-End Developer and Economist, with experience in project management, machine learning, and leadership roles; devoted to functional programming and analyzing mathematical models to solve emerging economic problems
                </font>
              </p>
              <hr class="style17"/>
             
             </div>   
           <figure>
                <img src="http://i.maniadb.com/images/artist/116/116122.jpg" id="imgR">
              
            </figure>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div id="midSec">    
          <section>
            <h2>
              <center>
                 <font color="#2F4F4F" size="20">
                Portfolio
                 </font>      
              </center>  
              </h2>
             </section>
          
         </div>
     </body>
```

```
<!--setup a home button at the bottom-->




[![Space is in between Portfolio and the brief summary][1]][1]
```

Comment: firstly edit ur code, so many incorrect things in ur code.  `<li><a  href="/About me">About Me</li></a>`

Comment: closing tags are off

Comment: And the body start after a div ?

Comment: The `<header>` tag and the `<footer>` tag should still be inside the `<body>` tag. I suggest you research more on basic HTML, it will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an h2 in your code that has a margin.

```
h2{margin: 0;}
```

This will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`h2` by default has a margin top . Remove that.

Also, your HTML is not correct . ( that's why i post this as an answer, to explain to the op the problems from his html )

**The biggest problem** is that you nested `ul` inside `h2` . This practice is not valid.

As stated in the doc

> Most elements that are categorized as phrasing content can only contain elements that are themselves categorized as phrasing content, not any flow content.

Heading tags like `h1`,`h2` etc. are pharsing content, `ul` is a `flow content` . So you cannot put `ul` inside `h2`

You can check your HTML here > [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) and check docs here > [documentation](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#heading-content)

**Second problem** is that you write `<li><a  href="/About me">About Me</li></a>`

So you first open li, then a but you close first the li and then the a. You need to close the a before closing the li. `a` being a child of `li` . Correct form :

`<li><a href="/About me">About Me</a></li>`

**Another problem** is using tags that are no longer supported in HTML5 . `font`,`center` . ( also the use of `size` is not supported either) You either use inline styles for example `<h2 style="font-size:10px;text-align:center">` or you can use CSS styles separately .

These are just the problems i see from a first look over your code

Comment: " _Another problem is using tags that are no longer supported in HTML5: font_ " Those elements are actually obsolete, but they do work in HTML5 because it is being threatened as a custom element. However, the expected styling effects that you see in old browsers (I'm talking about HTML3.2- ...) isn't being applied in the newest browsers.

Comment: @KarelG i meant that they are not working as the OP might expect so they are not supported .  `<font>` is no different from `<example>` :) .

Answer (score 1):

```
h2{margin-top:0}
```

will fix the issue